# Difference usage of document level, sentence level and aspect level in sentiment analysis

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-mining, sentiment-analysis

I'm studying about Sentiment analysis. And I wonder for what purpose we should use document level, for what we use sentence level and for what we should use aspect level.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: This question may not be appropriate to SO. I suggested moving this to https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-linguistics, or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp